# What's the proper term for converting a string into a variable/class/method?

Tags: php

I know it sounds so dumb but people were asking me about it and I don't have a proper answer.

Like

```
$var = "var1";
$var1 = "hello";

echo $$var;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Evilness, hackery, not-knowing-arrays, trying-to-make-maintainers-cry, ... - pick one that applies.

Comment: You want to echo both $var and $var1? Could you clean up your question?

Comment: @Colum: OP wants to echo $var1. PHP expands $$var to $var1

Comment: @The Guy Of Doom I learned something new. Dont think I will ever use it, but I learned it

Comment: @Colum: 'The more you know' :D. It is pretty useless in most cases, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You are talking about Variable variables :)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Wait, is that the only warning the PHP folks have concerning variable variables? Next time someone complains about that language's reputation...

Comment: @delnan: We see a lot of warnings, tips, infos and more. I wish i knew language internals :)

Comment: Care to clarify what this warning actually means?

Comment: @Gumbo: No, check out the docs :-) I considered it important for the OP to know about. Link is provided for the OP to know more about :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: You just quoted the manual but it doesn’t explain it. So how about you clarify it as you seem to consider it mentionable.

Comment: @Gumbo: It is better now I believe. OP's question is answered. Rest, over there in the manual. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

They're called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

It can be called *"wrong program design"* and "time to learn arrays"

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to specify a variable by using the value of another variable is called [variable variables](http://php.net/language.variables.variable).

This might seem cool is some way. But I rather think that it’s an obscure technique and can also tempt to use some dangerous pattern like exporting input values to the global variable space (just like [*register globals*](http://php.net/security.globals) does).

There are also some restrictions with variable variables:

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with [PHP's Superglobal arrays](http://php.net/language.variables.superglobals) within functions or class methods. The variable `$this` is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

This basically describes that the following is not possible:

```
$name = '_GET';  // identifier of the superglobal $_GET
$args = $$name;
```

But there’s also a workaround for this by using the [`$GLOBALS` array](http://php.net/reserved.variables.globals):

```
$name = '_GET';
$args = $GLOBALS[$name];
```